# How to change color with three.js?

Tags: three.js

Im having issues, I downloaded the source code for a simple three.js project to play around with for fun. Im trying to change the colors of the object but when changing the hex code, saving, and refreshing the browser, the color DOES NOT CHANGE. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function init() {

// heeere we go !

var blue = new THREE.Color(0x7658ef);
var pink = new THREE.Color(0xfca4c5);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
var shape = [];
geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(2.5,0);
material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
shape[0] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
shape[1] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
shape[2] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
shape[0].position.set(0,5,0);
shape[1].position.set(0,5,0);
shape[2].position.set(0,5,0);
scene.add(shape[0],shape[1],shape[2]);

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xfca4c5);
light.position.set(0,250,0);
scene.add(light);

camera.position.set(3,4,10); // x y z

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    shape[0].rotation.x += 0.035;
    shape[0].rotation.y -= 0.005;
    shape[1].rotation.y += 0.015;
    shape[1].rotation.z -= 0.005;
    shape[2].rotation.z -= 0.025;
    shape[2].rotation.x += 0.005;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

}

init();

Comment: what color are you changing to what? There are several colors in your code.

Comment: the top 2, var pink and var blue. Tried changing both to 33cccc and 333333 and nothing happened lol

Comment: but your `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });` uses a blue. thats the one you need to change. Those variables are not used anywhere (in your posted code)

Answer (score 1):

`THREE.Color` is an object. `THREE.Material` does some magic when you provide certain types of arguments to certain parameters. So when you provide a string or a number as a color, three constructs a Color object out of it.

`yourMaterial.color instanceof THREE.Color === true`

To change it you need to do

`yourMaterial.color.setRGB(1,0,1)`